# Compliments — for people, things or both?

Tags: nouns, word-usage

Are compliments applicable both to people and things, or to people only?

Comment: You could compliment or insult a thing, but since it won't acknowledge your compliment (honestly, it's like talking to a brick wall), there's not much point. But if you could call it a compliment, a common one would be "Wow, the scenery is beautiful"

Comment: Although people often accept compliments on behalf of inanimate objects: 'Oh, I love your new curtains' ... 'Why, thank you!'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Macmillan specifically states that a [*compliment*](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/compliment) (the noun) is "something nice that you say to praise **someone**."

Oxford likewise asserts that to *[compliment](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/compliment?q=compliment)* (the verb) is to "politely congratulate or praise (**someone**) for something."

Other dictionaries (such as [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/compliment)) leave the definition open in an oddly truncated way: "to express esteem, respect, affection, or admiration **to** : to pay a compliment **to**."

By the last definition, one can compliment a thing, like the weather.

Comment: So "Oh, what a beautiful morning!" is best left unsaid?

Comment: @bib That's an [exclamation](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/exclamation), not a compliment.

Comment: Arguably, Balaam compliments his donkey when pushed.

Comment: Visitors can compliment the weather; anything belonging to or associated with the addressee may be complimented as a way of complimenting the addressee.